# Differentiable function that merges two straight lines

Tags: functions

I require a function $f(x)$ that is differentiable and is equal to two straight lines $y=0$ and $y=mx+c$ except where they meet (which needs to be smooth so that it's differentiable). Here's a diagram of what I mean:

[image]

Can anyone propose a suitable function?

Comment: You might be interested in learning about mollifiers:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A branch of hyperbola,

$$y=\sqrt{x^2+1}+x.$$

(You can adapt to your coefficients.)

Comment: This will be asymptotic to your lines but not follow them.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way is to make a circle between them.  Choose a radius for the circle, say $1$.  Find the line $1$ unit above the horizontal line and the line $1$ unit left of the sloping one.  Find their intersection.  That is the center of the circle.  Use the circle between the points of tangency and the lines outside that.  This will have continuous first derivative.

Answer (score 1):

You can use spline interpolation, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation.